# Set Chart Series Color in Word

Tags: c#, office-interop, system.drawing, word-automation

I want to set different colors for all series in my chart in Word 2010 through a windows service using VS 2012 and interop assemblies for word.

I know to set it like:

```
    Series series1.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = (int)XlRgbColor.xlDarkGoldenrod;
```

**BUT I want to set exact RGB values e.g.(111,154,169) and not some predefined colors (not even hexValues).**

I am finding some way to do this using System.Drawing.Color structure but in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Series series1.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(111,154,169).ToArgb()
```

Note that at least in Excel the R and B values are sometimes reversed, so if the color won' match try to switch the R and B components.

See this quote from another thread: [Changing an Excel cell's backcolor using hex results in Excel displaying completely different color in the spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423456/changing-an-excel-cells-backcolor-using-hex-results-in-excel-displaying-complet)

> I finally figured it out, after lots of tests, and it was something really simple. Apparently, Excel's Interop library has a bug and is reversing the Red and Blue values, so instead of passing it a hex of RGB, I need to pass BGR, and suddenly the colors work just fine. I'm amazed that this bug isn't documented anywhere else on the internet.
>
> So if anyone else ever runs into this problem, simply pass Excel values in BGR values. (Or if using Color.FromArgb(), pass in Color.FromArgb(B, G, R))

Comment: Thanks I even went to the extent of writing this dummy code: series1.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = int.Parse(Color.FromArgb(31,111,154,169).Name, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);